# Java read timeout doesnt work

Tags: java, android, sockets

I try to connect with my server by using socket on android. I want it to work like this; when i send a request to the server, if there is a response, call my response function. If the timeout of 500 ms happens (will check the exception and the boolean i set), i want to execute another function. But with this code im using, when i send something to the server and wait for response, it executes the onServerResponse function if there is a response and doesnt do anything(hangs) when there is not a response. How can i edit this code so it will throw a timeout exception when there is no response?

```
            boolean control = false;
            try{
                Socket socket = new Socket();
                socket.setSoTimeout(500);
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP),SERVER_PORT));
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));
                bw.write("asdasd\n");
                bw.flush();
                control = true;
                int readInt = -1;
                String read = null;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
                while((readInt = socket.getInputStream().read()) != -1){
                    sb.append((char)readInt);
                }
                read = sb.toString();
                if(read != null && read.trim().length() > 0){ onServerResponse(read); }
            }catch(Exception e){ Log.v("Main", "GOT AN ERROR: "+e+control); }
```

Problem solved, see the comments for answer.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted and if the call to `read()` blocks for more than 500ms it will throw an exception.  It's likely the connection attempt is what is blocking.

Comment: Hey Brian, when i set my server to send a response, i recieve the response via onServerResponse otherwise it just hangs at while((readInt = socket.getInputStream().read()) != -1){ and doesnt throws any exception.

Comment: Well i found what was causing the problems after i set breakpoints. Apparently system doesnt hangs, it just goes without throwing any exception or something. Think i need to modify my code to work with it. Thanks anyways.

Comment: 500ms is a ridiculously short read timeout in the first place. It should be several seconds at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, SERVER_PORT);
// 500ms is too short, up to you.
// normal time would be 5 to 20 seconds, depends on network (intranet/internet)
socket.connect(sockaddr, 500);
// 500ms to timeout reading from the socket
socket.setSoTimeout(500);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but [`setSoTimeout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) only applies to reads on the socket after it is connected, not to establishing the connection itself. For that, use the [`socket.connect(SocketAddress address, int timout)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress,%20int%29) overload.) overload. You probably want to use both.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, that was one of the flaws of my code but didnt solve my problem. I even moved setSoTimeout before the reading line incase of the connect method overrides the read timeout or something. But it didnt solve my problem. I still dont get anything if server doesnt sends any response, system stays hanged.